# mostrar todos los datos que coincidan con mi variable mysql

Tags: php, mysql

buen dia, necesito que en el momento de ejecutar mi consulta me muestre todos los datos que coincidan con mi variable "2" en mi campo id, lo he intentado pero solo me muestra el primer campo que coincidan y no me muestra mas.

```
$sql = "select * from talleres where id=2";
```

Comment: No entiendo bien. Tienes una variable en Php y quieres seleccionar los registros donde el campo talleres valga tu variable php (que vale 2)?

Comment: Falta el código que usas para mostrar los datos. Por lo general se usa un `while` para ir vaciando el buffer de resultados.

Comment: Coloca la estructura de tu tabla "talleres" y el código que usas para recuperar esos datos.